# what is the cause of java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1 in this simplified example of Rest Services?

Tags: java, rest

curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/julian/resources/MyRestService/convert/222

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  5.1.0  - Error report

## HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

---

**type** Exception report

**message**Internal Server Error

**description**The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
```

**note** The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  5.1.0  logs.

---

#### GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  5.1.0

(base)

```
package book.jakarta.julian;

import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
/**
 * 
 * Rest Web Service
 *
 */
@ApplicationPath("/resources")
@Path("MyRestService")
public class Julian  extends Application {
        
    // http://localhost:8080/julian/resources/MyRestService/convert/0123
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain") 
    @Path("convert/{inNum : .*}")
            
    public String add(
            @PathParam("inNum") String inNum) {
        
          // get first digit ignore rest 
          int intemp = Integer.parseInt(inNum.substring(0, 1));
            
          return "" + (intemp + 3) ;
      }
}
```

Comment: return inNum to see the value of it first, seems it is a empty String.

Comment: You're right with this  revised code there the return value is blank , so why isn't the values  /0123 picked up ?                                                                                                     // curl -X GET  http://localhost:8080/julian/resources/MyRestService/convert/0123
 @GET
 @Produces("text/plain") 
 @Path("convert/{inNum : .*}")
        public String add(
            @PathParam("inNum") String inNum) {
  
     return ""+ inNum;
     
      }
}

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish using this regular expression {inNum : .*}

Comment: Change your regular expression to "convert/{inNum: .+}"

Comment: Cold you answer your question. So to help anyone that have issue in the future.

Comment: I figured out the silly error,  it was the wrong import. import javax.websocket.server.PathParam; should import javax. ws.rs.PathParam; {inNum:.*} is okay syntax. The same be achieved using "/convert{inNum}" . Just ones those where there was no error and it was driving me crazy. I let eclipse do the import and wasn't paying attention.

Comment: Cold ? You can see for yourself in the code I originally published,  this particluar type  error which does not cause  an error message, it just drives you stir crazy.

Comment: sorry I meant could you please write the answer so others can find it quickly without reading the comments. Also it is better to change .* to .+. Because .* will accept empty parameter and it will throw internal error if the user used this request http://localhost:8080/julian/resources/MyRestService/convert/ . In fact to avoid parsing issue if the user send a string [0-9]+ is the correct regular expression.